# Why does the carbocation in this scheme react under elimination conditions rather than being attacked by water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

In the final step of the mechanism, elimination occurs over substitution, why is this?

> [image: Reaction scheme]

Comment: For tertiary carbocations elimination products are generally produced, nothing special here.  On the other hand rearrangement that happens earlier is a bit interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that water is a very weak nucleophile and substitution does happen reversibly, but usually dissociates immediately. After which, the final reaction shown happens.

There is likely a (very) minor product that follows along the substitution pathway with an alcohol final product.

Comment: So if water added to the carbocation, the c-o is cleaved mostly as oppose to deprotonating and forming the alcohol?

Comment: That is essentially correct

Comment: Moreover, for the bottom two examples here: https://prnt.sc/hny81u why is the substitution product formed over elimination?